# Is there a way to make a read-only paragraph with openxml?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am generating a word document with OpenXML and C#. I want to block (read only) a paragraph in the text so that it cannot be removed in editing by user.

I did some unsuccessful tests that would make the whole document read-only, but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
var file = $"{directory}\\{fileName}.docx";
using (WordprocessingDocument package =
    WordprocessingDocument.Create(file, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    package.AddMainDocumentPart();

    var documentProtection = new DocumentProtection();
    documentProtection.Edit = DocumentProtectionValues.ReadOnly;

    package.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>();
    package.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings = new Settings();

    package.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.AppendChild(documentProtection);
    package.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Save();

    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(DocBody);
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

    Process.Start(file);
}
```

Below is the code I have written to generate the paragraphs:

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
var run = new Run();
var properties = new RunProperties();
var paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();

properties.FontSize = new FontSize();
properties.FontSize.Val = new StringValue("20");
properties.RunFonts = new RunFonts()
{
    Ascii = "Arial"
};
paragraphProperties.Justification = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };

paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties);
run.Append(properties);

var text = new Text("Text content...") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };

run.Append(text);
paragraph.Append(run);

DocBody.Append(paragraph);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Word doesn't really support "read-only" as it's a text editor. The only way to achieve it is with some kind of protection. You're going to need to to some experimenting in the Word UI until you find something that fits your needs. I suggest you start with a content control, go into the properties and set "cannot be edited". If that works for you, look at the document with the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to see how to create it. If that's not going to work for you, ask in an end-user venue (like SuperUser) about other options.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: I've added an answer that shows the required Open XML markup and C# code.

Answer (score 2):

The practical (but not 100% safe) solution is to wrap your protected paragraph or paragraphs in a locked Rich Text content control, i.e., an instance of `SdtBlock` that is configured such that users can't edit or delete the content control and its contents.

Here is some sample markup that shows a locked content control with a paragraph protected in this way and another paragraph outside of that content control.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:sdt>
      <w:sdtPr>
        <w:lock w:val="sdtContentLocked"/>
      </w:sdtPr>
      <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p>
          <w:r>
            <w:t>This is a protected paragraph.</w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>This is another, unprotected paragraph.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Take note of the `w:lock` element, which is represented by the `Lock` class in the Open XML SDK.

The C# code required to create the above `w:sdt` element is the following:

```cs
var sdt =
    new SdtBlock(
        new SdtProperties(
            new Lock { Val = LockingValues.SdtContentLocked }),
        new SdtContentBlock(
            new Paragraph(
                new Run(
                    new Text("This is a protected paragraph.")))));
```

Comment: This is the only way to lock paragraph (restrict editing lock all). But It only worked with MsWord, and it doesn't work when opening this docx in LibreOffice. I'm still struggling to search for this solution.